# How to get System time in Netbeans?

Tags: java, date, time

I want to display system time(not date) into a JLabel. Can I use this date for comparison?

Background: I am developing a Netbeans Java Project- Multiplex Ticket Booking System.
The user should not be able to book a ticket if the movie had already started.

I don't know Core Java. 
So please make the answer lengthy and clear so that even a newbie can understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.getTime(); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
time.setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

time   --->  name of `JLabel`

Answer (score 0):

To show the current Time you can use

```
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    jLabel1.setText("The current time is "+sdf.format(d));
```

---

To find whether the movie has started or not :

We can store the start time of the movie in a Date datatype and make a function which would take start time of movie as input and compare it with current date to find if ticket's for movie can be booked or not

```
boolean Has_movie_started(Date movie_start_date){
        //gets the current time 
        Date current_time = new Date();
        //calculates the difference in Milliseconds between start of movie and current time 

        long difference_milliseconds = movie_start_date.getTime()-current_time.getTime();

        //getTime() method returns how many milliseconds have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT


        boolean movie_started;

      // if the difference is positive that means that movie has much more milliseconds and then current date.  

            if(difference_milliseconds>0){
                movie_started = false;
            }
            else{
                movie_started = true;
            }

        return movie_started;
    }
```

This function returns false if the movie is yet to start else true that is the movie has started.
You can use this to determine if the ticket for that movie can be booked or not.
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(d)
```

output: Tue Apr 02 11:32:45 CAT 2019
This works 100% of the time guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I should like contribute the modern answer. The `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes used in the other answers are all poorly designed and fortunately long outdated.

### java.time

```
    ZoneId cinemaTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Tucuman");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                    .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("es"));

    LocalDateTime movieStartTime = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.APRIL, 2, 8, 30);

    ZonedDateTime systemTime = ZonedDateTime.now(cinemaTimeZone);
    String displayTime = systemTime.format(timeFormatter);
    timeLabel.setText(displayTime);

    if (systemTime.isAfter(movieStartTime.atZone(cinemaTimeZone))) {
        System.out.println("Movie has started, no more tickets will be sold.");
    }
```

This will display a string like `8:02:40` in your `JLabel` (I assumed it was called `timeLabel`, but you can change that of course).

I am using a built-in localized time format for formatting the time (without the date). You can control how terse or wordy of a format you like by supplying format style `FULL`, `LONG`, `MEDIUM` or `SHORT`. And you control the cultural style by supplying a locale.

`ZonedDateTime.now()` gives us the current time, which we use for comparing to the start time of the movie. The comparison should take place in the movie theatre’s time zone, of course (if you didn’t want America/Argentina/Tucuman, place something else).

Since I ran the code *before* 8:30 in that time zone (the movie start time), it did *not* print the *Movie has started* message. If we run it later, it will.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining the use of java.time.